# Deleted partition on dual Linux boot, booted to grub

Tags: dual-boot, grub, boot-loader

I need to avoid data / OS loss on a dual laptop where I am unexpectedly booting into GRUB after a disk operation.

I have a machine with an Ubuntu-like distro and until a moment ago Xubuntu. The Xubuntu OS had a bpfilter problem, so I backed up data on its partition and deleted it from Ubuntu. I had previously inspected the boot managers with `efibootmgr` and the system had been stable for some time.

The laptop originally used a multi boot boot manager (when it was Ubuntu + MacOS). When I replaced MacOS with Xubuntu the boot manager that came with Xubuntu took priority. I inspected it with the `efibootmgr` tool and both bootloaders were there, along with the backup MacOS one, but Xbuntu had taken higher priority. I decided that was fine because it was much faster, so I left it and it worked fine for a long time. It offered both OSs and recovery.

I rebooted after deleting the broken partition and now it just goes straight into GRUB. There is are no options prior. I put in a live flash drive with another Linux distro and so far it doesn’t recognize it. Is there any way to force the other Linux boot loader to start?

I held down the Option key during startup and it shows me EFI Boot with a hard disk icon and one with a USB flash disk icon. The flash drive one just freezes when selected. The hard disk shows

> ```
> LoadImage failed: Not found
> Device Path:…
> ```

In the long PciRoot device path it mentions refind, the EFI multibootloader. I’ve seen this screen before when everything still worked. I think it was when I selected the wrong option from the boot menu back when I used to have one…

Comment: I tried exit but it just never returns. https://askubuntu.com/questions/538083/computer-boots-automatically-into-gnu-grub-no-other-options#538305

Comment: All flavors of Ubuntu would have same entry in UEFI. The difference is in the ESP. Last install updates ESP with a grub configfile entry to full install of grub. You can just edit the grub in the ESP with correct UUID. Or chroot into your install, or use Boot-Repair to totally reinstall grub just to update the 3 line grub. cfg in the ESP. Manual boot: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054032/grub-loads-instead-of-ubuntu-whenever-my-hp-streambook-reboots  & grub in ESP, just correct UUID: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205982/how-make-external-usb-disk-bootable-for-bios-and-uefi

Comment: @oldfred Thanks for your help. The live OS drive for Xubuntu worked, so I reinstalled and now it's fine.